# Automating GUI testing using C#

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, gui-testing

I am doing on a project to built automatic GUI testing for graphical application in .NET. I will use C# but i am trying to reading to get some ideas. But I don't have any idea on how to record and replay back. So can you give me your ideas.

Comment: by graphical application do you mean 3D graphics or just a normal GUI? Testing 3D applications "through the GUI" is tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog from the visual studio team that goes over this exact topic. It's about how they tested pre-wpf and post-wpf.

> This post covers an overview of techniques that we used to create and maintain automated user interface regression tests for Visual Studio. Regression tests are a type of software test that, collectively, aim to be an oracle of expected functionality for the target application, run often against new builds of product – they aim to uncover regressions in behavior introduced in a new build.

[Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/30/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-6-automated-ui-testing.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)!

There is also the TFS Test that has web tests, which tie into load test. Nice platform, but if you are not already using TFS then it is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I don't think there is a **good** answer out there for this. There are two options, however, that work *okay*:

1. [Visual Studio Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678655.aspx) (as durilai suggested)
2. [Telerik's Web Testing](http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools.aspx) (both a free version and a version with a cost but depending on your UI, this may or may not work)

Answer (score 1):

A good (commercial) C#-based product is [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/), it may do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your Visual Studio to 2010 version? It has a build-in coded-ui automated testing feature, which could be used to record and replay back the test for win form.

Comment: Might be interesting that this is only true for Premium and Ultimate Editions, or an eval thereof.

Answer (score 0):

- Selenium
- Watin

  are some options that come to mind

Answer (score 0):

To test C# apps there are a few things we have had success with:

1. [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx)
2. [TestPlant](http://www.testplant.com/)

and possibly would be the new [VSTS 2010 features](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsautotest/thread/5dddc0be-0b78-4914-b739-ce0353b59383), though we haven't tried them